# If $\sec(\theta) +\tan(\theta) = \frac{3}{2}$, then what are the other trig ratios?

Tags: trigonometry

> If $$\sec(\theta) + \tan(\theta) = \frac{3}{2}$$
>   then how do I find the other trig ratios?

I tried squaring but could not get to anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \sec^2 \theta - \tan^2 \theta= 1 $$
$$ (\sec\theta - \tan\theta)(\sec\theta + \tan\theta) = 1 $$
I hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Assuming $\cos(\theta)\neq 0$,
$$\sec(\theta) + \tan(\theta) = \frac{3}{2}\implies 1+\sin(\theta)= \frac{3}{2}\cos(\theta) $$ Now, use the tangent half-angle substitution $t=\tan(\frac\theta 2)$ to get $$5 t^2+4 t-1=0\implies (t+1) (5 t-1)=0$$ One of the roots cannot be used (which one and why ?).

From the solution $\theta=2\tan^{-1}(t)$ and all other trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \large \sec{\theta} + \tan{\theta} \equiv \frac{(\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} + \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}})^2}{\cos^2{\frac{\theta}{2}} - \sin^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}} \equiv \frac{1+\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}}{1-\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}} \equiv \tan{\left( \frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)}$

The rest is trivial.